# Is Geo API limited to businesses in US only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, geocoding

Can someone help with the info whether GeoAPI is limited to locate businesses within US only?
Looked around in their documentation but could not locate it. The limitation I found was for 20k query per key. But nothing related to businesses location limitation.

OR

Is there any other API that allows to locate businesses around the world?

Answer (score 0):

The query limit is based on the type of account you have. 20K is the maximum for the free account. See the [pricing page](http://geoapi.com/pricing.html) for details.

Comment: looking for businesses primarily. Is there a page which can tell if the API or any package provides information about the businesses around the world instead of just the US?